# iOS issue with multiple files uploading one by one

Tags: ios

I have a collection of file Urls. I need to upload all files from the list one by one. Once a file got uploaded server sends a returnId to save. And need to show progress accordingly.

Hence I have tried the following,-

```
- (NSURLSession *)uploadSession
{
    static NSURLSession *defaultSession = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t uploadToken;
    dispatch_once(&uploadToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.xyz.abc"];
        configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
        defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });

    return defaultSession;
}

-(NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadFileWithUrl:(NSString *)fileUrl
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"ploadableUrl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; // default
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSString *base64str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", kAPIAccessUsername, kAPIAccessPassword];
    NSData *base64data = [base64str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64Encoded = [base64data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64Encoded];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---9999999999";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; // over-ridding for multipart/form-data;

    /*  body of the post */
    NSMutableData *reqBodyData = [NSMutableData data];
    [reqBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"fileN"]; // "data" is the parameter required
    [reqBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [reqBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *uploadableData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileUrl]];
    [reqBodyData appendData:uploadableData];
    [reqBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:reqBodyData];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [reqBodyData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];

    NSURLSession *session = [self uploadSession];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:nil];
    DLog(@"upload taskIdentifier ---------------------> %lu", (unsigned long)dataTask.taskIdentifier);
    [dataTask resume];
    return dataTask;
}

- (void)initiateUpload
{
    uploadTask = [self uploadFileWithUrl:[_fileUrlCollections objectAtIndex:self.index]]; // initially index = 0
}

- (void)dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"CompletetaskIdentifier -> %ld", dataTask.taskIdentifier);

    if (data)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]];
        if (!_uploadedIdCollections)
            _uploadedIdCollections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
        [_uploadedIdCollections addObject:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"savedId"]];
        self.index++;
        if([_fileUrlCollections count] > self.index)
        {
            NSLog(@"UPLOADING NEXT FILE");
            [self initiateUpload];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"UPLOADED ALL FILES");
        }
    }
}
```

once my file with index 0 is uploaded, server sends me proper returnId, then after saving that, I'm trying to upload file with index 1. But its not uploading anymore.
Don't know what's missing/wrong.

Need immediate suggestions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You should watch this with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or equivalent tool and confirm whether uploads are not taking place and make sure the requests are not malformed.
2. Why do you want to upload them one at a time? You pay significant performance penalty for that. It's also a little at odds with the traditional background session operation of "let me queue up a bunch of uploads and they'll carry on even after this app terminates".

   Let's imagine you're queuing many requests: If the user leaves the app, you don't want to restart the app in the background after every download. You'd rather have the `NSURLSession` daemon do it's magic and just let you know when everything is done.
3. I'm surprised this uploads at all, because upload tasks generally don't use body of `NSMutableURLRequest`, but rather use the `fromFile` parameter of `uploadTaskWithRequest` for the body of the request. This can be confirmed by watching the requests in Charles.

   By the way, depending upon the size of the files being uploaded, this can be a more efficient use of memory, too.
4. You're using background session:

   - So, have you implemented `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in your app delegate? Are you saving that `completionHandler`?
   - In your `NSURLSessionDelegate`, having you implemented `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`? I assume once you're done, you're calling the `completionHandler` that you received above?
5. By the way, you're triggering the next upload upon `didReceiveData`. If your intent was to really do these sequentially (debatable; see point 2), you might want to trigger the next upload in `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:`, instead.

   You want to implement `didCompleteWithError`, anyway, so you can detect whether an error occurred.
6. You're specifying the `Authorization` header for some `req` variable that is unrelated to the `request` we're building here. Make sure you're setting the header in the right object.

   You're also setting `Content-Type` for the `req` object to be JSON, and obviously this isn't JSON.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the suggestions. Few things to confirm, point 4 and 5 have been implemented. 6th is required for our server to respond to any call we are making (security reason). Content-Type is being over-ridden to===>     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; // over-ridding for multipart/form-data;

Comment: I don't follow you re #6: You're setting auth for some `req` object _that you don't appear to use here._ What is `req`? Did you mean `request`?

Comment: I have noticed that the second call to server is happening but the delegate methods `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend`, `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error`, `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;` are not getting called

Comment: one new issue arrised, now some of the time the above issue happens after 4th/5th/6th uploads